# AWS: instance down due to low memory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My Amazon instance( EC2 t2small ) is running low on disk space, now I want to increase space immediately to keep my site up.[currently its struggling with low space, and sometimes ssh is not responding and sometimes the site says connection to DB failed.]

The challenge I am facing is that I didn't had an Elastic IP when I created the instance, now If I change the instance type or add additional volume to my instance, I will have to 'stop' my instance for a while, and stopping an instance will release the public IP.

I CANNOT lose this IP as all my external domain names are pointing to this IP.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have stop an instance to add a volume to the instance. You do have to stop your instance to resize the root volume to a larger size.

You will probably have to shutdown mysql and or your webserver to move files to the new volume. But you should be able to do so without stopping your instance all together.

Comment: And use your OS volume management (LVM?) to be able to expand a filesystem without stopping it. Also avoid static IPs in DNS references, specially if not EIP. You can add a second ENI with an EIP to the instance, change the DNS, wait replication and solve this issue without downtime.

Comment: @JulioFaerman I am not able to understand, could you please refer me to a tutorial so I can read more on this? Thanks.

Comment: which OS are you using?

Comment: the latest ubuntu, ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: also, what will happen if I add a EIP to my current instance? Which IP will be in use? Public IP or the EIP? or both?

Comment: @JulioFaerman "add a second ENI with an EIP" Are you suggesting to create another new instance with an EIP and use a better storage volume in this instance?

Comment: No, create a new Elastic Network Interface, attach a new Elastic IP to  it and then attach the ENI to the instance you already have. This way you will have two IPs and be able to transition your DNS without downtime. For the disks, create a new logical volume using LVM, backed by EBS volumes, so you can scale the filesystem without downtime in the future.